# UICollectionView adding button to cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm adding a button to a cell of a collection view as below

```
- (void)activateDeletionMode:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"deletion mode");

        if(self.isDeleteActive == NO){
            self.isDeleteActive = YES;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[gr locationInView:self.collectionView]];
            UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            self.deletedIndexpath = indexPath.row;


            self.deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [self.deleteButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(deleteImage:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.deleteButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 10, 10);

            [cell addSubview:self.deleteButton];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the cell is reused when the collection view is scrolled, I see the button displayed in this cell too.  How do I avoid this happening?  Code for collection view below:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.image.image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I've done things like this, when adding the view add a tag:

```
self.deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 10, 10);

//Mark the view with a tag so we can grab it later
self.deleteButton.tag = DELETE_BUTTON_TAG;
[cell addSubview:self.deleteButton];
```

Then remove it from any new recycled cells:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Remove the delete view if it exists
    [[cell viewWithTag:DELETE_BUTTON_TAG] removeFromSuperview];
    cell.image.image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```